# Кроссплатформенная интеграция с КриптоПро (Azure, .Net Core)

Tags: docker, azure, .net, core

Есть .net core приложение, которое работает в Azure (в докере, linux). Приложению необходимо шифровать данные, используя КриптоПро. Локально приложение разрабатывается в двух ОС - Windows и MacOS. Решал ли кто-нибудь задачу, как кроссплатформенно работать с КриптоПро?

Answer (score 0):

У них есть экзешник `cprocsp`, который работает кросплатформенно. Таким образом, вызывая этот экзешник с нужными ключами и обрабатывая вывод парсером, вы теоретически добьетесь нужного результата.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, стоит посмотреть на .NET Core с поддержкой КриптоПро CSP: https://github.com/CryptoPro/corefx.

Comment: А это не то, что устанавливается вот из такого нугет файла Microsoft.Private.CoreFx.NETCoreApp.4.7.0-dev.20465.1.nupkg ? У меня в Windows все ок, а вот в докере под linux вот такая ошибка: Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libcapi10' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibcapi10. И не пойму, чего-именно не хватает.